# INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM WHERE ...) to Linq

Tags: sql, linq

How do i convert the following sql to a linq statement?

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM Table1 as A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ColumnB = "Something1") B on A.Column1 = B.ColumnA
WHERE A.Column3 = "Something2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for an inner join, your sql would be much more readable with just

```
 select a.Column1, a.Column2
 from Table1 a
 join Table2 b on b.Column1 = a.Column1
 where a.Column3 = 'Something2' and b.ColumnB = 'Something1'
```

Now, you can just do, in pseudo linq

```
from a in Table1
join b in Table2 on a.Column1 equals b.Column1
where b.ColumnB == "Something1" and a.Column3 = ="Something2"
select new {
  col1 = a.Column1,
  col2 = a.Column2
};
```

or also

```
from a in Table1.Where(t => t.Column3 == "Something2"
join b in Table2.Where(t => t.ColumnB == "Something1")
          on a.Column1 equals b.Column1
select new  {
  col1 = a.Column1,
  col2 = a.Column2
};
```

Comment: woow! it worked. I used the ".Where(t => t.Column3 == "Something2"" version. Thanks a lot